# How can I set a different vertex parent for different pieces of mesh

Tags: mesh, parent, vertex-paint

I have a dragon with teeth in its mouth.
I would like to define for each tooth a parent vertex from the mouth so that they stay in place when the mouth moves.
The thing is that all the teeth are in the same mesh but they are different islands.
Is it even possible to do something like this?